# Is there a way to await a Future completion that will not block the execution thread in Act Framework?

Tags: actframework

I have a controller action that depends on several parallel `Future` tasks running on several `Executors`. Right now I'm starting several tasks on the Executors, then calling `future.get()` in the action method to assemble the results for display to the caller.

That's fine, in that I get some execution speed improvements as the tasks are executed in parallel. However it's not great in that the controller execution thread is blocked throughout. Ideally that thread would go and serve more requests until the Futures were complete.

In Play Framework v1 this would be done with `await(future)` and I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in Act. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `await(future)` mechanism implemented in ActFramework. There is a plan to provide similar support like Spring WebFlux in Act 2.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a roadmap or plan available somewhere for Act 2? And most critically - do you expect there to be many breaking changes for Act 2? As someone who never migrated to Play 2 I'm not looking to recreate that experience :)

Comment: @MattHall here is the roadmap (in my mind ;-)): 1.9 - refactory of the act-db  framework; 2.0 - drop java7 support plus support to pure async request handling; 2.1 - update act-asm to support new java versions (11, 13); 3.0 - totally rewrite osgl libraries and actframework

Comment: I expect there will be some incompatibility between 1.8 and 1.9, mainly on act-db, however I promise it is just going to be much easier to use and the migration should be quite smooth; With regarding to 2.0, there might be little impactible changes but Ie expect most of the change is on new feature, not drop existing features.

Comment: In terms of timing, the plan is get 1.9 out by Jun 2020 and 2.0 out by Dec 2020; BTW I am on your side with regarding to play2, and that's why I create Act, the aim is a better play1, but never aother play2 ;-)